# Export XML file using Builder Gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this class. I am using builder gem here.

```
class ClientsExportXML

  def initialize(current_user)
    @file = File.new("#{Rails.root}/public/data.xml", 'w')
    @clients = Repository::Clients.new(current_user).all
    @builder = Builder::XmlMarkup.new(:target=> @file, :indent=> 2)
  end

  def build
    @builder.instruct! :xml, :version=>"1.0", :encoding=>"UTF-8", :company => "Tougg"
    @builder.clients do
      @clients.each do |c|
        @builder.client do
          @builder.name(c.name)
          @builder.razao_social(c.corporate_name)
          @builder.rg(c.rg)
          @builder.cpf(c.cpf)
          @builder.inscricao_estadual(c.state_registration)
          @builder.cnpj(c.cnpj)
          @builder.email(c.email)

          if c.address
            @builder.numero_rua(c.address.street_name)
            @builder.bairro(c.address.district)
            @builder.complement(c.address.complement)
            @builder.cep(c.address.zipcode)
            @builder.cidade_estado("#{City.find(c.address.city_id).name}/#{City.find(c.address.city_id).state.symbol}")
          end

          @builder.telefones do
            c.phones.each do |f|
              @builder.numero(f.number)
            end
          end

          @builder.notas do
            c.notes.each do |n|
              @builder.nota do
                @builder.nota(n.note)
                @builder.adicionada_em(n.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%y"))
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
    @file.close
  end
end
```

Everything works fine when I execute this in rails console, for example. But, I dont know why, when I try add this in some controller:

```
  def export
    ....
     ClientsExportXML.new(current_user).build
    ...
  end
```

The file is created at public/data.xml but with no content (empty file).

I am a little confusing about what can may be happening here.

Thanks in advance

Édipo

## solved

I change file to an instance variable and close the file at end of method build. I updated the code to reflect this.

Comment: Have you try to require the gem? something like require 'rubygems'
  require_gem 'builder' or require 'builder'

Comment: Yes @Jean ```require 'builder'``` at top of ClientsExportXML file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `@builder.target!` on the last line of the `build` method. `target!` method generates XML from the the builder.

Edit:

```
def export
  ..
  File.open(file_path, "w") do |f|
    f.write(ClientsExportXML.new(current_user).build)
  end
  ..
end
```

Do your `export` method looks something like this?

Comment: Hi @edariedl same result. Empty file :(

Comment: Hi @elf, I updated the answer. Do your `export` method looks like the example?

Comment: No @edariedl. I just use build method.

Comment: Oh sorry, I see it now. You are creating file, but you don't write nothing into it. Before line `@file.close` in the `build` method add line `@file.write(@builder.target!)`. I hope this will finally work.